# Shortcode with pagination advancing multiple queries

Tags: functions, shortcode, query, pagination, paginate-links

I have some shortcode that I am using. The shortcode itself is working. The shortcode has pagination because it's cycling through a picture gallery.

The pagination itself works, but when it advances, it also advances the pagination for other picture galleries that are using the same shortcode.

My question is, how can I have the same shortcode, but only advance that specific gallery when I use the pagination, instead of advancing all the galleries using that shortcode? For example, if I click on page 2 for gallery 2017, gallery 2016 stays on page 1.

The shortcode I am using on the page looks like: `[halloffame rml_folder="16"]` and `[halloffame rml_folder="14"]`

The actual shortcode in my functions file looks like:

```
function picture_gallery($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'rml_folder' => 1
    ), $atts));

    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    query_posts("post_status=inherit&post_type=attachment&rml_folder=".$rml_folder."&orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=12&paged=".$paged);

    if ( have_posts() ) :
        $return_string .= '<div id="album">';
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                $return_string .= '<div class="gallery">';
                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');
                    $return_string .= '<a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID).'" class="simplelightbox">'.$image.'</a>';
                $return_string .= '</div>';
            endwhile;
        $return_string .= '</div>';
    endif;

    $return_string .= '<div id="pagi">';
        $return_string .= '<div class="wrap">';
            $args = array(
                'prev_text' => __('<span class="left"></span><span class="ion-android-arrow-dropleft"></span>'),
                'next_text' => __('<span class="ion-android-arrow-dropright"></span><span class="right"></span>')
            );
            $return_string .= paginate_links($args);
        $return_string .= '</div>';
    $return_string .= '</div>';

    global $wp_query;
    $current_page = get_query_var( 'paged' );
    $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    $return_string .= '<p align="center">(Page: '.$current_page.' of '.$pages.')</p>';

    wp_reset_query();

    return $return_string;
}

function register_shortcodes(){
    add_shortcode('halloffame', 'picture_gallery');
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

I'm definitely not tied to this code, if there is a better way to do this, please don't hesitate!

Any ideas?

** UPDATE **
I have updated my shortcode to use `WP_Query` instead of `query_posts`, my code is similar, but now looks like:

```
function picture_gallery($atts){

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'rml_folder' => 1
    ), $atts));

    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

    $picture_gallery = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'rml_folder' => $rml_folder,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'asc',
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'paged' => $paged
    ));

    if ( $picture_gallery->have_posts() ) :
        $return_string .= '<div id="album">';
            while ( $picture_gallery->have_posts() ) : $picture_gallery->the_post();
                $return_string .= '<div class="gallery">';
                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');
                    $return_string .= '<a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID).'" class="simplelightbox">'.$image.'</a>';
                $return_string .= '</div>';
            endwhile;
        $return_string .= '</div>';
    endif;

    $return_string .= '<div id="pagi">';
        $return_string .= '<div class="wrap">';
            $return_string .= paginate_links(array(
                'prev_text' => __('<span class="left"></span><span class="ion-android-arrow-dropleft"></span>'),
                'next_text' => __('<span class="ion-android-arrow-dropright"></span><span class="right"></span>'),
                'total' => $picture_gallery->max_num_pages
            ));
        $return_string .= '</div>';
    $return_string .= '</div>';

    $current = get_query_var( 'paged' );
    $total = $picture_gallery->max_num_pages;
    $return_string .= '<p align="center">(Page: '.$current.' of '.$total.')</p>';

    return $return_string;

    wp_reset_query();
}

function register_shortcodes(){
    add_shortcode('halloffame', 'picture_gallery');
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

Now, I'm back to my original problem, which is the pagination for my shortcode advances all multiple queries on the same page...still looking into that.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when it was all said and done I went with another solution. I could not figure out how to implement the suggested solution. I went with a grid layout that uses infinite scroll as it's pagination. If anyone else is interested, there is a tutorial I followed here: https://allurewebsolutions.com/implement-masonry-isotope-infinite-scroll-imagesloaded-wordpress

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

I did a gallery pagination by converting all the stuff from galleries into arrays, and then json_encoding that and passing it to javascript.
If you were to to that you could have multiple scripts:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
var thisgallery = <?php echo the gallery; ?>
function process pagination (){
     code for pagination
}
}
```

And because they are all in separate jquery document ready functions they wouldn't see each other, so they would iterate independently and without page reloads.

Edit: 
The modified shortcode function would look like this:

```
<?php 
function picture_gallery($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'rml_folder' => 1
    ), $atts));

    query_posts("post_status=inherit&post_type=attachment&rml_folder=".$rml_folder."&orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=-1");
    $return_string = "";
    $pics = array();
    if ( have_posts() ) :
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                $p = array(
                    'image' => wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium'),
                    'url' => wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID)
                );
                $pics[] = $p;
            endwhile;
    endif;
    $pics = json_encode($pics);

    $return_string .= "<div class='js-gallery-$rml_folder'></div>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        var pics = $pics;
        console.log(pics);
        $('.js-gallery-$rml_folder').html(pics[0][image]);
    }
    </script>"

    wp_reset_query();

    return $return_string;
}
```

**Edit:** added a div to show the first picture in gallery.

Comment: So, I would put this in my `<head></head>` tags or in my `functions.php` file?

Comment: You would put this as part of the output of the shortcode. Of course the JS code must be inside `<script>` tags.
The idea is that instead of echoing the gallery you make a json object with all your links to your pictures in the gallery and other stuff that is needed, and use JS or jquery to manipulate the html.

Comment: Also for this to work you need all your post in the query posts not just 12.

Comment: I'll give it a go and let you know...thanks for the help!

Comment: I edited my answer with the code for the shortcode function which should log to the console the object what you can later manipulate in js.

Comment: WP_Query should be used in place of query_posts.

Comment: @Milo: I tried that originally and for some reason I couldn't get the "Page 1 of 9" or the pagination to work properly. When I switched it to query_posts it worked like a champ. Not sure what I was doing wrong, but I agree it should be WP_Query.

Comment: @Milo: I figured out how to update my query (thanks to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMscydyViZw), looks like I was missing the total variable in my `paginate_links` function.

Comment: @D.Dan: So, I add the code you provided for the shortcode and the pagination in my functions.php file (replacing what I am currently using). Then, I add-in my actual pagination code (that I am currently using) and that's it? I'm just making sure I understand how to implement the code :-)

Comment: The solution that I was suggesting was to totally abandon the wordpress pagination code that you're now using. So what my above code is doing is passing an array to a JS variable called pics. Only inside that jquery function of that script tag can you access it, and so if you were to write a function that's say on a click of a button were to put the content of the first 12 elements from the array(accompanied with the html stuff just like you concatinated in php) in a div (essentially replacing the html that was already in it), and on a click of another button place the second 12 and so on...

Comment: @D.Dan: I added the code, and success! Some data is returned: https://jsfiddle.net/aLx8znvg/, just not sure how to get that to display on the page...do I echo `$pics` or return `$pics`, not sure how to work with what's being returned.

Comment: For this to work you need jQuery DOM manipulation. It has nothing to do with echoing because it's not php. Basically you would have an empty div for the gallery, and some buttons (like 1,2,3 or previous, next) - which would be attached to a jQuery function that would change the contents of that empty div (if 1 is pressed it would put the first 12 gallery elements in it, if the 2 then 13th-24th element and so on). jQuery is already loaded, inside the `jQuery(document).ready(function` you can add whatever function you want, and the divs can go before the script tag in the `$return_string`.

Comment: Hey there, I'll give this another go and see if I can make it work...thanks for the help!

Comment: Unfortuantely, I couldn't figure out how to get this method implemented, so I've decided to go in a different direction...thank you so much for providing me with a possible solution.